# values change when scrolling my tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

my tableview changes values when I scroll up or down. It seems to use the same values from other parts of the table. I imagine its an error in my cell creation, here is the code.
Please tell me what I did wrong, thank you!

EDITED ADDED WHOLE CODE

```
//global indexpath to remember which cell tapped
NSIndexPath *globalPath;
@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

//Load implementation once per launch
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self linkInputTableToDelegate];
    _temporaryResultsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _flurryArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _numberOfSections=6;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    [InputTable reloadData];

    textFromUserDefaults=[[[HelperMethods alloc]init]getObjectUserDefault:@"textFiltered"];
    [self addTextToFlurryArrayForFlurryAndSavedLists:_textFromUserDefaults];



}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

}

- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
     self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}


//Makes the input table respond to delegate table view methods
-(void)linkInputTableToDelegate{
    _inputTable.dataSource=self;
    _inputTable.delegate=self;
}

-(void)performSearch:(NSString*)text{
    //do search
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    int numberOfRows=_numberOfSections;

    //Rows for iPhone 4
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==480) {
        numberOfRows=numberOfRows;
        //Rows for iPhone 5
    }else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height==568){
        numberOfRows=numberOfRows+1;
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //In reality groups are created with 1 row inside, this is to allow spacing between the rows

    return 1;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kCellID = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
    }

    //Is the cell the same as the one clicked when going to ingredient filter
    BOOL cellIndexPathSameAsSelected=[self isCellIndexSameAsPreviousClicked:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    if (cellIndexPathSameAsSelected && _textFromUserDefaults!=nil) {

        if (![cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:_textFromUserDefaults]) {

            cell.textLabel.text=_textFromUserDefaults;
            [self performTextSearch:_textFromUserDefaults];
        }

    }
    return cell;
}

//Compares the previous clicked cell with the cell now selected
-(BOOL)isCellIndexSameAsPreviousClicked: (NSIndexPath*)cellPath{

    if (cellPath.row == globalPath.row && globalPath.section==cellPath.section) {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)updateTableViewWithExtraRow :(NSIndexPath*)rowSelected{
    NSLog(@"number of sections =%i",_numberOfSections);
    if (rowSelected.section == _numberOfSections) {
        _numberOfSections ++;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;
    [[[HelperMethods alloc]init]saveObjectToUserDefaults:cellText :@"textFiltered"];
    globalPath = indexPath;
    [self updateTableViewWithExtraRow:indexPath];
}

-(void)addTextToFlurryArrayForFlurryAndSavedLists:(NSString*)text{
    if ([_flurryArray count]==0 &&[text length]>0) {
        [_flurryArray addObject:text];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<[_flurryArray count];i++) {
        NSString *textInArray=[_flurryArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if (![textInArray isEqualToString:text]) {
            [_flurryArray addObject:text];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"Total number of saved items = %i",[_flurryArray count]);
}

// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Comment: You need to keep it in mind ever that tableview cells are reusable.. So you need to save the store and repopulate the values whenever the cells are visible to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are only changing the texts in the cells, when those conditions are met. For example, when your `cellIndexPathSameAsSelected` is `NO`, you leave the cell unmodified. So you should add an `else` and do some settings there too.

**EDIT:**

```
if (cellIndexPathSameAsSelected && _textFromUserDefaults!=nil) {

    if (![cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:_textFromUserDefaults]) {

        cell.textLabel.text=_textFromUserDefaults;
        [self performTextSearch:_textFromUserDefaults];
    }

} else {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString string];
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but when I click a cell I go into a new VC (a text filter), after selecting a match it returns here with that text (in user defaults) so I only want to fill the cell if there is a text from the filter, or if it is the same text (in case cancel was pressed in the filter)

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. So you have a number of cells, the user taps on one of them, does some things in the next screen, and after returns to this screen again, you want to display fewer cells than before? Cause in that case you would want to change your data source, so the `numberOfRowsInSection:` method returns the exact number of cells. It's not a good thing to fill only the ones you need, and leave the rest.

Comment: there are 5 rows here, when user clicks a row he is taken to pick a string (using a filter of words). Before leaving, I save the index of the cell clicked. When coming back user returns with a string from filter. I then want to put that string on the same row before we left to filter ingredients. (Table is actually many sections each with 1 row in between, to allow spacing between cells)

Comment: I can post the whole thing if you think it will help

Comment: So you would want the other cells to remain empty (except the tapped one)? Look at the edit I made.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Please look at the full code for reference

Answer (score 0):

After your `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];` call, you have to check if your cell can actually be reusable or not with the followings statements :

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:...];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this

```
static NSString *kCellID = @"Cell";

// Acquire the cell if possible. 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
if (cell == nil) // Not possible to re-use cell, so create a new cell
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
}
```